# Class mark has a fatal flaw

Tags: statistics

As we know, while calculating the mean of a grouped frequency distribution we assume that the frequency is centred around the class mark (25-30 has its class mark as $27.5$). Hence we multiply the class mark with frequency and add all such products. By doing this we try to get the best possible probabilistic or nearest estimate of the actual mean of the data.

But but but...
The class interval can't have the value of $30$ as it lies in the succeeding class.
Hence the 'true' class mark shall be given as $$\frac{upper - 1 + lower} 2$$ ($25-30$ should have it as $27$).
It also makes sense as follows:
the values that the distribution can hold are $25,26,27,28,29$. Hence the middlemost value is 27 and it is also the best value if we look at a probabilistic way to get the closest value to the actual mean.

I would be glad if someone can help me out with this...

Comment: "the values that the distribution can hold are 25,26,27,28,29". The class can hold $29.2$, or $29.5$ or even $29.99999999999999999$. Do you get it now?

Comment: I basically learnt it rn in class 10 and thought i 'broke the code'
Thanks a lot

Comment: It is affected by what possibilities there are for actual values, e.g. integers or real numbers